# jQuery Booklet and parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I've been following 2 differents tutorials in jQuery. One for parallax and another one to make a booklet. Both load images in a different way. My images are loaded but in the booklet they are supposed to be in the pages and the pages not displayed yet should be hidden. The problem is all of my divs (with image and text) are shown and pages don't flip.
I'm getting a JavaScript error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  on $mybook.show().booklet({`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body class="loading">
    <div id="preload">
        <img src="img/slide1.jpg">
        <img src="img/slide2.jpg">
        <img src="img/slide3.jpg">
    </div>

    <main>
        <section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide">
            <div class="bcg">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="slide-2">
            <div class="bcg">
                <div class="hsContainer">
                    <div class="hsContent">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </section>

        <section id="slide-3">
            <div class="bcg">
                <div class="hsContainer">
                    <div class="hsContent">

                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="slide-4">
            <div class="bcg">
                <div class="hsContainer">
                    <div class="hsContent">
                        <h1 class="even" >Portfolio</h1>
                        <div class="book_wrapper">
                            <a id="next_page_button"></a>
                            <a id="prev_page_button"></a>
                            <div id="loading" class="loading">Loading pages...</div>
                            <div id="mybook" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="b-load">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                                        <h1 class="port" >Slider Gallery</h1>
                                        <p>This tutorial is about creating a creative gallery with a
                                            slider for the thumbnails. The idea is to have an expanding
                                            </p>
                                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/" target="_blank" class="article">Article</a>
                                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SliderGallery/" target="_blank" class="demo">Demo</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
                                        <h1 class="port" >Animated Portfolio Gallery</h1>
                                        <p>Today we will create an animated portfolio gallery with jQuery.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/14/animated-portfolio-gallery/" target="_blank" class="article">Article</a>
                                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedPortfolioGallery/" target="_blank" class="demo">Demo</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
                                        <h1 class="port" >Annotation Overlay Effect</h1>
                                        <p>Today we will create a simple overlay effect to display annotations in e.g. portfolio
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/12/annotation-overlay-effect/" target="_blank" class="article">Article</a>
                                        <a href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnnotationOverlayEffect/" target="_blank" class="demo">Demo</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="slide-5" class="homeSlide">
            <div class="bcg">
                <div class="hsContainer">
                    <div class="hsContent">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
( function( $ ) {

// Setup variables
$window = $(window);
$slide = $('.homeSlide');
$body = $('body');

//FadeIn all sections   
$body.imagesLoaded( function() {
    setTimeout(function() {

          // Resize sections
          adjustWindow();

          // Fade in sections
          $body.removeClass('loading').addClass('loaded');

    }, 800);
});

function adjustWindow(){

    // Init Skrollr


    // Get window size
    winH = $window.height();

    // Keep minimum height 550
    if(winH <= 550) {
        winH = 550;
    }

    // Resize our slides
    $slide.height(winH);

    // Refresh Skrollr after resizing our sections
}
    } )( jQuery );

$(function() {
            var $mybook         = $('#mybook');
            var $bttn_next      = $('#next_page_button');
            var $bttn_prev      = $('#prev_page_button');
            var $loading        = $('#loading');
            var $mybook_images  = $mybook.find('img');
            var cnt_images      = $mybook_images.length - 3;
            var loaded          = 0;
            //preload all the images in the book,
            //and then call the booklet plugin

            $mybook_images.each(function(){
                var $img    = $(this);
                var source  = $img.attr('src');
                $('<img/>').load(function(){
                    ++loaded;
                    if(loaded == cnt_images){
                        $loading.hide();
                        $bttn_next.show();
                        $bttn_prev.show();
                        $mybook.show().booklet({
                            name:               null,                            // name of the booklet to display in the document title bar
                            width:              800,                             // container width
                            height:             500,                             // container height
                            speed:              600,                             // speed of the transition between pages
                            direction:          'LTR',                           // direction of the overall content organization, default LTR, left to right, can be RTL for languages which read right to left
                            startingPage:       0,                               // index of the first page to be displayed
                            easing:             'easeInOutQuad',                 // easing method for complete transition
                            easeIn:             'easeInQuad',                    // easing method for first half of transition
                            easeOut:            'easeOutQuad',                   // easing method for second half of transition

                            closed:             true,                           // start with the book "closed", will add empty pages to beginning and end of book
                            closedFrontTitle:   null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and "pageSelector", determines title of blank starting page
                            closedFrontChapter: null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and "chapterSelector", determines chapter name of blank starting page
                            closedBackTitle:    null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and "pageSelector", determines chapter name of blank ending page
                            closedBackChapter:  null,                            // used with "closed", "menu" and "chapterSelector", determines chapter name of blank ending page
                            covers:             false,                           // used with  "closed", makes first and last pages into covers, without page numbers (if enabled)

                            pagePadding:        10,                              // padding for each page wrapper
                            pageNumbers:        true,                            // display page numbers on each page

                            hovers:             false,                            // enables preview pageturn hover animation, shows a small preview of previous or next page on hover
                            overlays:           false,                            // enables navigation using a page sized overlay, when enabled links inside the content will not be clickable
                            tabs:               false,                           // adds tabs along the top of the pages
                            tabWidth:           60,                              // set the width of the tabs
                            tabHeight:          20,                              // set the height of the tabs
                            arrows:             false,                           // adds arrows overlayed over the book edges
                            cursor:             'pointer',                       // cursor CSS setting for side bar areas

                            hash:               false,                           // enables navigation using a hash string, ex: #/page/1 for page 1, will affect all booklets with 'hash' enabled
                            keyboard:           true,                            // enables navigation with arrow keys (left: previous, right: next)
                            next:               $bttn_next,                     // selector for element to use as click trigger for next page
                            prev:               $bttn_prev,                     // selector for element to use as click trigger for previous page

                            menu:               null,                            // selector for element to use as the menu area, required for 'pageSelector'
                            pageSelector:       false,                           // enables navigation with a dropdown menu of pages, requires 'menu'
                            chapterSelector:    false,                           // enables navigation with a dropdown menu of chapters, determined by the "rel" attribute, requires 'menu'

                            shadows:            true,                            // display shadows on page animations
                            shadowTopFwdWidth:  166,                             // shadow width for top forward anim
                            shadowTopBackWidth: 166,                             // shadow width for top back anim
                            shadowBtmWidth:     50,                              // shadow width for bottom shadow

                            before:             function(){},                    // callback invoked before each page turn animation
                            after:              function(){}                     // callback invoked after each page turn animation
                        });
                    }
                }).attr('src', source);
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this loading order:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></sc‌​ript>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.js"></script> 
<script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="js/skrollr.js"></script>     
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Nevermind. I think you're loading jquery twice. The plugin is being attached to the first instance, but then you're loading it again with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

---

Any chance that `$().booklet` is undefined? Like if jquery.booklet.1.1.0.min.js couldn't load for some reason. You could type "$().booklet" into the console and it should say *function*.... if the plugin loaded and *undefined* if it didn't.

Sorry to put this as an answer instead of a comment, but I don't have enough points to comment yet.

Comment: I tried to put only one jquery but my page then keeps loading. It never finish loading. I just tried typing $().booklet in the console and I got undefined. But I don't know why the booklet won't load

Comment: You're removing `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and not the top one right? Are you getting any errors when the page keeps loading?

Comment: You need to remove jquery 1.4.4, it's very very old and jquery 1.9.1 needs to load BEFORE jqueryui. Also, your booklet.js is a very old version. booklet is at v 1.4.4 now. You are basically loading your javascrpt files in the wrong order. booklet needs to load after imagesloaded.

Comment: try this loading order:   
`<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script src="booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="booklet/jquery.booklet.1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>`

Comment: Ahh, but clayton got the credit....;-) I will enter my comment as an answer and maybe you could accept it.